# discord.py error in ban command role hierarchy

Tags: discord.py

my code:

```py
    #Ban command
    @bot.command()
    async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason='nothing'):
        #to check if user has permissions
        if has_permissions(ban_members=True):
            #to not let admins ban each other
            check = False
            for i in member.roles:
                if i in ctx.author.roles[1:]:
                    check = True
    
            if(check):
                await ctx.send('❌ Cant ban admins/moderators.')
            else:
                
                await member.ban(reason=reason)
                await ctx.send(f'✓ {member} has been banned')
        else:
            await ctx.send(' you dont have that permission')
```

The problem is that users who don't have perms if used the command does not print: `you don't have that permission` and I get an error.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `ctx.author.guild_permissions`. Or using discord.py's method of `@bot.has_permissions(ban_members=True)` just after `@bot.command()`

```py
    @bot.command()
    async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason='nothing'):
        #to check if user has permissions
        if ctx.author.guild_permissions.ban_members:
            #to not let admins ban each other
            check = False
            for i in member.roles:
                if i in ctx.author.roles[1:]:
                    check = True
    
            if(check):
                await ctx.send('❌ Cant ban admins/moderators.')
            else:
                
                await member.ban(reason=reason)
                await ctx.send(f'✓ {member} has been banned')
        else:
            await ctx.send(' you dont have that permission')
```